# Does anyone know how to perform variable importance scoring for support vector machines in R language?

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm

I see that someone can use the varImp function in the caret package, but I get an error every time. Does anyone know how to do it?
I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could help me.

```
> sss<-train(shuxue~.,data=train,method="svmRadial")
Warning message:
In train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) :
  You are trying to do regression and your outcome only has two possible values Are you trying to do classification? If so, use a 2 level factor as your outcome column.
> varImp(sss)
Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ x, na.action = na.omit, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  参数'y'的种类(list)不对
In addition: Warning message:
In mean.default(y, rm.na = TRUE) : 参数不是数值也不是逻辑值：回覆NA
```

Comment: Did you read the warning/error messages? Do you understand what they are saying?

Comment: have you tried making your response variable (`shuxue`) a factor?

Comment: Can you share an example of what the data looks like, ideally using `dput()` - it's easier for others to help if we can run your code!